# OpenCL support on Leopard

Tags: macos, opencl

I want to use OpenCL in my software but I am running Leopard.

I will probably update to Snow Leopard later. In the mean time I would like to get started with OpenCL in Leopard. Setting up on 10.5 is confusing: most SDKs and articles assume that you must be using Snow Leopard. Searching for "Using OpenCL on Leopard" is completely useless, as you would expect.

I downloaded the cuda toolkit, devdriver and gpucomputing SDK from nvidia but the examples won't compile because OpenCL/opencl.h is not found. The OpenCL release notes don't mention MacOSX so again I think this is assuming that all Mac users are running Snow Leopard.

Where can I find OpenCL includes and libraries for Mac OSX 10.5 ?
Or, is this just a waste of time and I should go and get Snow Leopard ASAP ?

After upgrading to Snow Leopard I would like my software to support Leopard. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the headers necessary to compile OpenCL code are included with the Nvidia GPU Computing SDK (path is something like NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/OpenCL/common/inc/CL). You could copy or link these into the directory where your compiler looks for includes (/usr/include/CL/ on Linux, not sure for Mac).  Alternatively, you could get the headers from [khronos.org/registry/cl](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/).  The libraries themselves should be included with either the SDK or the cuda toolkit (I don't recall which).

Comment: I found the headers but I haven't been able to find the OpenCL libraries - if they were in one of the 3 files I installed. I have the CUDA framework though.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to upgrade to Snow Leopard. Also note that OpenCL really isn't ready for "prime time" software development on *any* platform yet. CUDA is much more mature than OpenCL and you should consider using CUDA rather than OpenCL if you want to develop and deploy GPGPU-dependent software in the near future.

Comment: Thanks, yes I want to deploy soon in my software. There are so many posts about OpenCL on SO and questions of an advanced nature to suggest that many people are already using it. Given that version 1.1 was released led me to believe that was more or less the last step. It's a bit of a shame that I'll have to learn CUDA first. What one or two criteria would you use to say it is ready for prime time ? I ask this because I expect that my users would be savvy enough to install OpenCL drivers just to run my software.

Comment: I suggest you put together a small benchmark that Is representative of the kind of code you need to run and try it with both CUDA and OpenCL. In general CUDA wins on performance, stability, tools, maturity, community support, etc. OpenCL offers the future possibility of being cross platform but if you want maximum performance then even this may be illusory.